# Print function name in which a pattern of string occurs

Tags: regex, powershell, automation, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am looking for a way to automate a manual task. I'm not sure if it's even possible.

 I have to find a pattern of string in all files in a project folder. It'a project of C#/.net project(if that matters at all). I have to also write the function name and file name where the pattern occurs, along with the full string that matches it. So far I've done following in `PowerShell`:

```
PS C:\trunk> Get-ChildItem "C:\trunk” -recurse | Select-String -pattern
“AlertMessage” | group path | select name
```

This prints file name where string pattern matches.

```
PS C:\trunk> Select-String -pattern "AlertMessage" -path
"C:\trunk\VATScan.Web\Areas \Administration\Controllers\HomeController.cs”
```

This prints line number and string that matches it in a given file.

Any pointers on how I can acheive my goal?

Comment: Write the function name? Do you mean identifying the C# function where AlertMessage is invoked?

Comment: @DavidBrabant That's right. I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Well, probably not possible with PowerShell only. Using a combination of Roslyn and PowerShell, maybe. But is it worth the effort?

Answer (score 1):

By no means perfect but at least this my fall under the category of pointer

```
$text = @"
Public Sub Bitchin()
    Dim AlertMe
End Sub

Private Sub Function() As something

End Function
"@

[void]($text -match "(?smi)((public|private)\W(sub|function)\W(.+?)\(.*?Alertme)")
$Matches[4]
```

This will look for a Function or Sub routine declaration with a single white space between words followed by the next occurrence of the word AlertMe

Need to get item 4 from `$Matches` since there are a bunch of capture groups.

A more concise explanation of the regex used can be found [here](http://regex101.com/r/gC6lB1/1)

Hopefully this will get you started or at least thinking. I am not familiar with c# declarations as `$text` is more of a VBA example but your should get the idea.